# How do I git-push to an FTP server?

Tags: linux, ftp, git

Has anyone managed to do a git-push to a repository on an FTP server? According to the man page of git-push

> Git natively supports ssh, git, http, https, **ftp**, ftps, and rsync protocols.

I can clone the remote repository but when I push I get the error message

```
error: Cannot access URL ftp://my-ftp-server/git/test.git/, return code 3
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Any clues? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and git version 1.7.9.5.

Comment: Run `curl --version` and see if it supports FTP. Also be aware that FTP paths are relative to your home directory on the server – `ftp://foo/git/test.git/` is `~/git/test.git/` and `ftp://foo/%2Fgit/test.git/` is `/git/test.git/`.

Comment: Yes, my curl installation indeed supports FTP. As far as I know the path should be OK as it is the same as the one I successfully cloned from (I'm doing `git push` with no additional arguments).